# Nginx returns 502 to browsers but works fine with curl

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a MediaWiki running in a kubernetes cluster. The kubernetes cluster is behind an nginx proxy with the following config:

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    upstream rancher {
        server 192.168.122.90:80;
    }

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default Upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name .domain;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://rancher;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            # This allows the ability for the execute shell window to remain open for up to 15 minutes. Without this parameter, the default is 1 minute and will automatically close.
            proxy_read_timeout 900s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

I can get to the main page of the wiki, but have to log in before using it. When I click to login using OAuth2 I get a 502 status from the nginx proxy server (nginx reports that the upstream ended the connection prematurely). If I do the same request with curl I get a 302 with the location of the authorization endpoint as expected. I really don't understand why it is like that. Not using the proxy and directly accessing the cluster (from the vm host) works just as normally but that isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not related to nginx, nor kubernetes. It was an issue with mediawiki, where compression had some funny behaviour. See more [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:W1xkngh7z9r8xh6v), if anyone encounters anything similar:)